# Is it ok to use tid-kijyun Swift-HTML-Parser to parse a real world html file from webpage

Tags: swift, html-parsing

So the thing is, I am new to programming, and Swift in particular. I completed some courses and now want to build something really simple: an app that gets the news from website and pushes it to a *Table View*.

Right now I am stuck on error:
`Optional(Error Domain=HTMLParserdomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTMLParserdomain error 1.)")`

The code I wrote is really simple. It's the example from the [tid-kijyun repo](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Swift-HTML-Parser) plus some code to get content of the HTML (`func perFormConnectionToGrabUrlContent`)

```
func perFormConnectionToGrabUrlContent(# url: String) -> NSString {
    let url = NSURL(string: url)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    var htmlContentTemp: NSString = ""
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
        (response, data, error) in
        htmlContentTemp = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        println(htmlContentTemp)
    }

    return htmlContentTemp
}

let html = perFormConnectionToGrabUrlContent(url: "http://www.google.com")
println(html)

var err: NSError?
var parser = HTMLParser(html: html, error: &err)
if err != nil {
    println(err)
    exit(1)
}

var bodyNode = parser.body

if let inputNodes = bodyNode?.findChildTags("a") {
    for node in inputNodes {
        println(node.contents)
    }
}

if let inputNodes = bodyNode?.findChildTags("a") {
    for node in inputNodes {
        println(node.contents)
        println(node.getAttributeNamed("href"))
    }
}
```

So the question still is, should I change something in code and it should really work like a charm, or should I better go access the database of website I am trying to reach and run some datebase queries or something like that instead?

Comment: That's not how asynchronous requests work. `html` will always be blank when you run this.

Comment: I checked that with print line statement, and html string content is printing out just fine, but even after I replaced the code in performConnectionToGrabUrlContent function using NSURLSession It still giving me the same error.